# How to exclude fields from being "upsert-ed" in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, upsert

```
var UserData = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.schema = Schema({
        userID: String,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        ...
        //many other fields.
        ...
        isActive: {type: "Boolean", default: true}
    },  { collection: 'UserData' });

    this.model = db.model('UserData', self.schema);

    this.upsert = function(object){
        //some logic
        self.model.update({userID: object.userID}, object, {upsert: true}, function(err){...});
    };
}
```

This code work fine except for the **isActive** will be overwritten during the upsert.

I want to implement the logic like this:

1. Default **isActive** to be true for new record.
2. When do upsert, keep **isActive** unchanged.

How to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Convert the document to an object and remove the property that you don't want to write. Then upsert the object.

```js
this.upsert = function (doc) {
    var object = doc.toObject();
    delete object.isActive;

    self.model.update({userID: object.userID}, object, {upsert: true}, function(err){...});
};
```